# Android get view from gridview with adapter

Tags: android, gridview, view, null, adapter

I have a `GridView` with an adapter (`ImageAdapter`). I need to get some special views in this `GridView`. But when I call `gridView.getChildAt(index)` it returns `null`. How can I manage to get the views?

Comment: make sure child exists in `index` or make sure you call `gridView.getChildAt(index)` after `gridView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: I am sure that the childs exist, and I call `gridView.getChildAt(index)` after setting the adapter. I know that the childs exist because they are drawn in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
grid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (!once) {
                        once = true;
                        grid.getChildAt(index);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Where once is boolean global member in your class.

Comment: that doesn't work since I need to set a listener to that view child. If I call grid.getAdapter.getItem(_index) I get an integer and not a view. I need to get back a view item.

Comment: getItem() return the Object you put in getView() implementation. So how it could give you integer?

Comment: it gives me integer because my adapter is an ImageAdapter which works with resource numbers of images. And this resource number is the integer I get back.

Comment: where you call to getChildAt()?

Comment: I call it several times, e.g. after the `onCreate`, and after special inputs. But every time when I call it the `gridView` has an `ImageAdapter`